# Get correct cursor image from Windows API

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to get cursor data (mask and color, if available) as a byte array using `GetDIBits()`, with the correct size and correct animation frame but it's proving to be unreliable.

Also, I would like to get or be able to simulate the multiple frames available in a cursor, such as what is possible when using `DrawIconEx()`, passing the cursorStep parameter.

Basically what I'm trying to emulate is part of the behavior of [`IDXGIOutputDuplication::GetFramePointerShape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication-getframepointershape), to get a buffer (byte[]) with the contents of the current cursor, just without having to rely on the DirectX library.

So, I want:

1. Get the cursor data as a `byte[]`, even with the mask working (**SOLVED**).
2. Get the cursor data with the correct size, not a fixed 32x32px cursor.
3. Get the actual animation frame of the cursor.

Just as the DXGI method provides if I'm using OutputDuplication, but in my case, I'm not.

---

### 1) Get the cursor mask correctly (solved):

**TL;DR:** Wrong data interpretation on my part.

I'm calling `GetDIBits()` once, passing null as the buffer parameter to get the details of the color/mask images and a second time to get the image.

It works all right with the color image but returns a wrong data size and wrong image content for the mask image.

Here's a comparison and the code sample.
Files ending with "2" were created by using `System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromHBitmap()` while the others were obtained from `GetDiBits()`.

[image: Here's a comparison]

For some reason, `GetDIBits()` returns this data (`BitmapInfoHeader`) for the mask. Also, only returns 128 bytes (256 if the mask has two frames, such as for the I-Beam/Text cursor), which is way too little for 32x32px or 32x64px masks.

[image: DiBits result]

Here's my code so far (it's C#):

```
WindowDeviceContext = User32.GetWindowDC(IntPtr.Zero);

//The parameter passed in the structs is just to be able to calculate the size of it. 
var cursorInfo = new CursorInfo(false);

if (!User32.GetCursorInfo(out cursorInfo))
    return;

if (cursorInfo.Flags != Native.Constants.CursorShowing)
{
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(cursorInfo.CursorHandle);
    return;
}

var iconHandle = User32.CopyIcon(cursorInfo.CursorHandle);

if (iconHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    User32.DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(cursorInfo.CursorHandle);
    return;
}

if (!User32.GetIconInfo(iconHandle, out var iconInfo))
{
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(iconInfo.Color);
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(iconInfo.Mask);

    User32.DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
    Gdi32.DeleteObject(cursorInfo.CursorHandle);
    return;
}

//Color.
var colorHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader(false);

//Gets the color image details.
Gdi32.GetDIBits(WindowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Color, 0, 0, null, ref colorHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);

if (colorHeader.Height != 0)
{
    colorHeader.Height *= -1;

    var colorBuffer = new byte[colorHeader.SizeImage];

    Gdi32.GetDIBits(WindowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Color, 0, (uint)(colorHeader.Height * -1), colorBuffer, ref colorHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);
    
    //Converts a byte array to image (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource) just for testing.
    var image = ImageUtil.ImageMethods.FromArray(colorBuffer, colorHeader.Width, colorHeader.Height * -1, 4); //4 channels

    using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"Color.png", FileMode.Create);
    var bmpEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    bmpEncoder.Save(fileStream);

    //Converts the HBitmap to Bitmap, just for testing too.
    var image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(iconInfo.Color);
    image2.Save(@"Color2.png");
}

//Mask.
var maskHeader = new BitmapInfoHeader(false);

//Gets the mask image details.
Gdi32.GetDIBits(WindowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Mask, 0, 0, null, ref maskHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);

if (maskHeader.Height != 0)
{
    maskHeader.Height *= -1;

    var maskBuffer = new byte[maskHeader.SizeImage];

    Gdi32.GetDIBits(WindowDeviceContext, iconInfo.Mask, 0, (uint) maskHeader.Height, maskBuffer, ref maskHeader, DibColorModes.RgbColors);
    
    //Converts a byte array to image (System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource) just for testing.
    var image = ImageUtil.ImageMethods.FromArray(maskBuffer.ToList(), maskHeader.Width, maskHeader.Height * -1, 1, 1);
    
    using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"Mask.png", FileMode.Create);
    var bmpEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    bmpEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    bmpEncoder.Save(fileStream);

    //Converts the HBitmap to Bitmap, just for testing too.
    var image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(iconInfo.Mask);
    image2.Save(@"Mask2.png");
}

Gdi32.DeleteObject(iconInfo.Color);
Gdi32.DeleteObject(iconInfo.Mask);
User32.DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
Gdi32.DeleteObject(cursorInfo.CursorHandle);
```

#### Solved:

With the proper interpretation of the bits per pixel of the mask image, this issue was solved.

```
public static BitmapSource FromArray(byte[] data, int width, int height, int channels, int bitsPerPixel = 32)
{
    var format = PixelFormats.Default;
    var stride = channels * ((bitsPerPixel * width + 31) / 32);

    //Abridged channel and bits by pixel to format converter.
    if (channels == 1)
    {
        format = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;
        stride = width / 8;
    }
    else if (channels == 3)
        format = PixelFormats.Bgr24; //RGB.
    else if (channels == 4)
        format = PixelFormats.Bgr32; //RGB + alpha.

    var wbm = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, format, null);
    wbm.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), data, stride, 0);

    return wbm;
}
```

---

### 2) Get the correct size of the cursor:

As noted above, I'm only getting cursor images of size 32x32 or 32x64 (for masks).

[image: DiBits result]

I've tried to increase the size being passed to `GetDIBits()`, but the image being returned is always the same size.

Even if the size in Windows 10/11 settings is set to a bigger cursor size.

[image]

The [`IDXGIOutputDuplication::GetFramePointerShape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutputduplication-getframepointershape) method returns a correct size, so it looks like it's possible. What does this method do in order to get the correct image size?

---

### 3) Get the actual cursor frame being displayed (for animated cursors):

As for the animation frame (steps) of the cursor, I don't see a way of getting multiple frames based on an index the same way that I would be able to draw with `DrawIconEx()`:

```
//If the cursor rate needs to be precisely captured, I could use this undocumented API:
//https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/user32/cursoricon.c#2325
//int rate = 0, num = 0;
//var ok1 = User32.GetCursorFrameInfo(cursorInfo.hCursor, IntPtr.Zero, 17, ref rate, ref num);

//CursorStep
var ok = User32.DrawIconEx(CompatibleDeviceContext, frame.CursorX - iconInfo.XHotspot, frame.CursorY - iconInfo.YHotspot, cursorInfo.CursorHandle, 0, 0, CursorStep, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0003);

if (!ok)
{
    CursorStep = 0;
    User32.DrawIconEx(CompatibleDeviceContext, frame.CursorX - iconInfo.XHotspot, frame.CursorY - iconInfo.YHotspot, cursorInfo.CursorHandle, 0, 0, CursorStep, IntPtr.Zero, 0x0003);
}
else
    CursorStep++;
```

Maybe I could draw the cursor color and masks separately using `DrawIconEx()` into two bitmaps (using the flags `DI_IMAGE` and `DI_MASK` in each call, passing the cursor step), and then getting the pixels using `GetDIBits()`?

But how to do that?

Comment: Mask is monochrome, 1 bit per pixel, 32×32=1024 bits=128 bytes. If cursor or icon has alpha channel then it is in color bitmap.

Comment: @DanielSęk Oh, thanks. So that part was just an issue of data interpretation. For some reason I thought it was 1 BYTE per pixel. Converting the `byte` array using the stride as `width / 8` created a correct image.

Comment: Modern cursors are full-alpha and have no mask: it’s not needed. The mask is synthesized on the fly just for you, based on pixel transparency of the cursor bitmap. So don’t presume that the mask exists: only look for it if the bitmap has no alpha channel. The mask synthesis is done for compatibility with software that predated widespread adoption of alpha channels for cursors. So, like, stuff 15 years old at least? Masks made sense as an implementation detail in times of software blotting and hardware that emulated this (old “super”-VGA cards).

Comment: I'm not assuming that masks or color bitmaps will always be available (you can see my code above). But the mask is **still** used now days in modern cursors for the inverted color effect, present in the **I-Beam** and **Crosshair** cursors. But anyway, that's not an issue anymore, my issue is getting the right size and animation frame.

Comment: I am not sure there is a public Win32/GDI API to do this at all, actually. Even the de-facto API to obtain the number of frames in an animated cursor and the duration of each (`GetCursorFrameInfo`) is not actually documented and public.

Answer (score 0):

> Get the cursor data with the correct size, not a fixed 32x32px cursor.

[Here is some Qt code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowscursor.cpp#L660-L677) that deals with it and returns proper cursor size.
It reads `CursorBaseSize` from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` and maps it to DPI-dependant cursor size.

> Get the actual animation frame of the cursor.

You can use `DrawIconEx` or undocumented `GetCursorFrameInfo`:

```cpp
// user32.dll
// provide either hcur or lpName and iFrame.
// outputs pjifRate (frame time in jiffles - 1/60 sec) and pccur (count of steps in animation sequence)
// returns cursor frame for iFrame
HCURSOR GetCursorFrameInfo(HCURSOR hcur, LPWSTR lpName, int iFrame, OUT LPDWORD pjifRate, OUT LPINT pccur);
```